# c++ invalid initialization of reference of type 'int*&' from expression of type 'order_record*'

Tags: c++

I have a dynamic array, and I have a function called double_size that is supposed to double the size of the array if it's full, and a function is_full to check if the array is full. I get the error when I'm calling the function double_size. My array is called INV

I have a class called order_record

array declartion:

```
order_record * INV = 0;
```

prototype:

```
void double_size(int * & INV, int count, int & size);
```

I get the error in the double_size call in:

```
if (is_full(count, size))
        {
            double_size(INV, count, size);
        }
```

double_size function:

```
void double_size(int * & INV, int count, int & size)
{
    -snip-
}
```

and I have no clue why I get an error.

Comment: `INV` is declared as a `order_record *`, but `double_size` wants an `int *`. Since the types aren't the same you get the error.

Comment: And please show the code where you are calling the double function.We want to see what arguments are you passing to the function.

Comment: @problematicDude `int *&x` is a reference to an int pointer.  The call `double_size(INV, count, size)` is expecting the first parameter to be an `int *`, but the `INV` variable is a `order_record *`.

Answer (score 0):

Needed `order_record * & INV` instead of `int * & INV` in the prototype and implementation of double_size. Thanks for the help.